# Building Angular and React components

Tags: lightning, angular, react, framework

I have been through tons of documents, searching the web I came across some [resources](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/171384/angularjs-4-on-visualforce-pages-or-in-lightning-components) but it hasn't really helped me.

I want to know how to ship an Angular and a React application (step by step) to Salesforce in VF and Lightning (using Lightning Container?).

The ones that I have seen on the web look like they'll fail security review.
I tried using `lightning:container` to build an aura component:

```
<lightning:container src="{!$Resource.AngularDemo+ '/index.html'}"/>
```

[image]

When I viewed the component in Lightning I received the following error:

> Refused to load the script '' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension: 'unsafe-eval'

Does this mean we can't use React or Angular in Lightning?
Can someone guide me to a proper resource?

Answer (score 0):

Christophe Coenraets has published a detailed blog on the subject:

[Lightning Container Component: Building Components with React, Angular, and Other Libraries](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/04/lightning-container-component-building-components-with-react-angular-and-other-libraries)